# Windows can't see a partition after i installed ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows, partitioning

this is my first time installing linux, i'm completely new here.
I installed ubuntu on top of Windows 10. I partitioned the drives as i installed ubuntu. Ubuntu can see and access all of them. But windows can't access one of the partitions. It's not the partition which ubuntu was installed, i didn't install any os in there. And it is in ntfs format. But still windows can't see it.

I cant post pictures since the account is new but I'm going to type in it's info from gparted.

/dev/sda3    file system:ntfs    mount point:blank    size:443.23 gib    used:325.42 gib    flags: boot

This partition was first mounted when i installed ubuntu, since i'm new i don't know what that means but i unmounted it thinking that may be the problem. But it didn't change anything.

edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbD8W.png here is a screenshot showing all my partitions on gparted. it is a mess i think, couldn't figure them out properly.
sda6 is where ubuntu is installed. its a clean partition.
sda7 i dont know what this is for
sda5 is where windows is installed, i've created a 20 gig partition for it and made a clean install there.
sda3 is the partition windows cant see.

Comment: The high size and usage tells me this probably the windows partition itself. What are the other partitions on the disk? Please edit your question to include the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: So, how many partitions have you got? Please include all of them. Just do what @HeatherBrown asked for.

Comment: i edited the post to add a screenshot link.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Windows Disk Management console using `start -> run -> diskmgmt.msc`

Find the right partition, right mouse click and mount it from there.

Comment: Factually I think this should be a Windows, not an Ubuntu question ;-)

Comment: there is no mount in the right click menu, only "change drive letter and paths, format, shrink volume, delete volume, properties and help"